# ActiveRecord attribute naming convention for counts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, naming-conventions

I have a model that contains the counts of certain types of items as well as a boolean of whether the type of item is present at all.

The user first says whether they have the attribute present (yes/no radio button, saved as a boolean attribute), and if yes, a textfield appears to enter the count of that item type (saved as a numeric attribute).

What would be the best way of naming these attributes?

I was thinking (let's take bottles as an example):

- **bool:**  has_bottles
- **count:** num_bottles

What are the general attribute naming conventions in Rails? (I saw some posts for booleans specifically, but not in general).

**Some extra notes:**

- I had considered using "_count", but it is already used as a cache for one-to-many relations, so it seems like a bad suffix choice.
- I had also considered changing the architecture to simply use the number 0 to refer to the case where none are present, but I wasn't able to figure out how to make this work elegantly with a radio-button that shows/hides the text field. I would have to set the textfield value to 0 when the user clicks "no" but then they would have to re-enter the value if toggling back to "yes".

Comment: From what I've seen X_count is the way to go. Also - can't you solve the form problem with javascript? I'm not positive why you have to define a model attribute for that.

Comment: Thanks.
You're right about the javascript. I just had to check which radio button is checked when I submit the form, and then set the text value to "0" if it is "no".

Comment: Restricting myself to the bottles example, _quantity_ can be a viable option